# Azure build failing due to Method not found: 'System.ReadOnlySpan`1<Char> Microsoft.IO.Path.GetFileName(System.ReadOnlySpan`1<Char>)

Tags: azure-devops

Ugh....Microsoft have done something.

All our builds that have been kicked off in the last few hours (approx 10:00 GMT) are failing on our "Build Solution step" failing because of the following error (from the logs):

`##[error]EXEC(0,0): Error : Error occurred during processing of input file 'XXX.XXX.dll' --> Method not found: 'System.ReadOnlySpan`1 Microsoft.IO.Path.GetFileName(System.ReadOnlySpan`1<Char>)'.`

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas on this? Nothing in our codebase has changed.

If you need more information please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FYI, this seems to be caused by a recent update to MSBuild (https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/pull/7680) that has updated the version of System.Memory.

It looks like the obfuscation tool you're using in your build pipeline is built against a previous version of System.Memory and now that the version provided by the MSBuild environment has changed, the obfuscation tool is broken. Most likely requires the obfuscation tool to be updated.

(PS. I'm just relaying the information that others have identified where other tools are having the same issue - see https://github.com/T4MVC/R4MVC/issues/172)

Comment: Thanks  - we managed to fix it in the end buy updating the obfuscation package as you also suggested. But its also good to know the WHY it was failing. Thanks